# Extract data from passport image in key values format using OCR

Tags: containers, ocr, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

My goal is to extract data from passport image in a key value format using OCR server based solution so that the data remains in onpremise.
I tried Azure Form Recognizer Container (Cognitive Service Form Recognizer API V1 Preview). But the results where not satisfactory since the model created from training data  was not able to extract any key value pair. I tried various training sample data and also referred https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/build-training-data-set but didn’t work

Can you please guide me how can I extract the data in a required format ?

Or Is there anyone who are aware of any other on server product, library or solution commercial or open source or even approach in .Net preferably which could assist in the following;

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you could consider this:

1. collect enough sample passport data, say 30 images, which representing the files you will be processing.
2. decided on which field you want to extract, use Form Recognizer's labeling tool to label the <key, value> pairs,  suggest labeling 5 - 10 files first.  train a model
3. use some test image to test the model
4. analyze the low accuracy <key, value> pair and add more training files.  repeat 3) and 4) until you get a good enough result.

-xin (MS Form Recognizer Team)

Comment: 1) Can we pass label files in "/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/train" API in form recognizer container ? and in step4, how can i pass more training files as it will create a new model and there is also a file size limit of 4MB ? please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: v1.0 doesn't support label file. Form Recognizer has released 2.0,  it supports label file. please refer to documents or use the label tool here: https://github.com/microsoft/ocr-form-tools

Comment: Am using V1.0 since i need a container based solution and V2.0 is not released yet on container.

Comment: got it, I will update you when our new release is ready.  thanks